# Synonym Request: amazon-efs and aws-elasticfilesystem

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both of the following tags refer to the same technology:

- [[amazon-efs]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs) - 172 questions ⭐
- [[aws-elasticfilesystem]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-elasticfilesystem) - 35 questions

On another note, in trying to pick a winner, we're currently all over the place in terms of choosing a canonical alias between [**aws vs. amazon**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)

[image: aws vs amazon aliases]

That said, I'd go with spelling out "amazon" in picking the winner as it looks to be slightly more popular.

Comment: Found another [tag:aws-efs] (x 20), all syn'd